# How did Bishop and Wolverine wake up?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In Days of Future past, we see Kitty sending Bishop and Wolverine back into the past. Then when they wake up, the future gets altered.

**How do they wake up?**

Does Kitty wake them up by stopping her power or they wake up themselves...? Not sure if this was explained in the movie.

Comment: I think you mean to ask how she controls how far back they go. I'm not sure why "waking up" would be a concern.

Comment: @phantom42 - Since time travel appears to be in realtime, the moment at which they wake up is critical to whether they've done enough to change the future

Comment: @phantom42, I think Kitty mentions: _"As long as you're back there, past and present will continue to coexist."_ So if they continue to 'sleep', those in the future could still die. Atleast that's the impression I got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kitty's power *seems* to be terminated **when the traveler has caused sufficient damage to the timeline to cause her to cease to exist**. We see this most clearly when Professor X (at the bidding of Wolverine) manages to convince Mystique not to kill Trask. At the precise moment of decision, the timeline fractures and all of the Sentinels (and the X-Men in the room) disappear. Presumably the ruined Earth disappears as well as the timeline disintegrates.

To a lesser degree, we see this in the scene with Bishop. There's no indication that she's *stopped* doing whatever she's doing, only that she senses that the timeline is breaking and that there's time for a witty quip before she disappears.

Comment: But wasn't this also pretty much the time when the future sentinels broke throught the door and attacked Kitty? In her explanations it sounded more like whenever he wakes up the timeline changes, not the other way around.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach - Except that there's no indication that either Wolverine or Bishop woke up.

Comment: It seemed like *she* caused them to wake up by losing contact (be that forcibly or accidentally). But I'm admittedly a little hazy on the details too, just showing some alternative interpretations.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach - Assuming her powers are demonstrated by the blue glow emanating from her hands, then she doesn't stop before she disappears